# How to change Google Map Center by clicking a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using Google Map API v3 and jQuery 1.11.0.

I have a Google Map in the following div:

```
<div id="googleMap" class="map_div"></div>
```

The **map.js** is outside html file, it is linked.

Now I have a button in another part of the html (**outside map**) like this:

```
<button id="3">Change center</button>
```

Now I want to add a on click event which will change the center of the map to new latitude and longitude.

So, I have JavaScript in HTML like this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("#3").click(function(){
            var center = new google.maps.LatLng(10.23,123.45);
            map.panTo(center);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Can anyone help me please? Thanks in advance for helping.

Comment: Not sure "3" is a valid ID (starting with a number). Any errors in the console?

Comment: Where is the "map" variable defined? It's not in your code.

Comment: You can't do that because in your function, the map object is probably not ready yet. You can do the same after you initialized the map, or even better, in a `google.maps.event.addDomListener`.

Comment: @JeremyThille `3` is a valid id with HTML5.

Comment: `map.panTo` was all I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Here is the code for ur problem:

```js
var map;
function initialize()
{
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(48.1293954,12.556663),//Setting Initial Position
    zoom: 10
  });
}

function newLocation(newLat,newLng)
{
 map.setCenter({
  lat : newLat,
  lng : newLng
 });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

//Setting Location with jQuery
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $("#1").on('click', function ()
    {
   newLocation(48.1293954,11.556663);
 });
  
 $("#2").on('click', function ()
    {
   newLocation(40.7033127,-73.979681);
 });
  
    $("#3").on('click', function ()
    {
   newLocation(55.749792,37.632495);
 });
});
```

```css
html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true"></script>

<button id="1" style="padding:10px; cursor:pointer;">Munich</button>
<button id="2" style="padding:10px;cursor:pointer;">New York</button>
<button id="3" style="padding:10px;cursor:pointer;">Moscow</button>
<br>
<br>
<div style="height:100%;" id="map-canvas"></div>
```

[**Live demo is here**](http://earth3dmap.com/change-center/) if u need more :).

Comment: This would work but it's ugly. Use an event listener instead.

Comment: Thanks MrUpsidown! I change it to a jQuery function.

Comment: Yes that's already better ;) See my answer for a pure google maps API solution.

Answer (score 15):

In your `initialize` function (or where you create the map) add the following code after you created the map object:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('3'), 'click', function () {

    map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(10.23,123.45));
});
```

Comment: Could you add zoom, mapTypeId, or other options as well?

Comment: Figured it out `map.setZoom(10);` and `map.setMapTypeId(google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE);` seemed to do the trick for me.

Comment: Yes, or event better, use `map.setOptions()` if you need to change multiple options at once.