# How do you recenter mapbox js after pushing button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, mapbox

So it's pretty straight forward with **googlemaps** api to recenter a map on a new city after pushing a button, but I need to use a custom map from **MapBox** for a project. Unfortunately, their documentation hasn't been helpful.

```js
var map;
function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(48.1293954,11.556663), // Munich Germany
    zoom: 10
  });
}

function newLocation(newLat,newLng) {
 map.setCenter({
  lat : newLat,
  lng : newLng
 });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
 <script>
$(document).ready(function () {
     $("#1").on('click', function () {
   newLocation(48.1293954,11.556663);
 });
  $("#2").on('click', function () {
   newLocation(40.7033127,-73.979681);
 });
   $("#3").on('click', function () {
   newLocation(55.749792,37.632495);
 });
});
```

This code is from another post: [How to change Google Map Center by clicking a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28499141/how-to-change-google-map-center-by-clicking-a-button)

My question is how do you do this with the **mapbox.js** and **leaflet api**?    Everything I have tried has failed.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I figured it out. You can use Leaflet's L.LatLng to add a new operator for the coordinates. It was .setView() function that threw me off.

```js
var map;

function initialize() {
    var coordinates = new L.LatLng(40.673859, -73.970114);
    map = new L.mapbox.map('map')
        .setView(coordinates, 12)
        .addLayer(L.mapbox.tileLayer('myMapID'));
  
}

function newLocation(newLat,newLng,newZoom) {
    var newCoord = new L.LatLng(newLat,newLng)
    map.setView(newCoord, newZoom);
}
  
window.addEventListener('load',initialize,false);


$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#1").on('click', function () {
        newLocation(40.765172,-73.978844,12);
    });
    $("#2").on('click', function () {
        newLocation(35,-75,4);
    });
    $("#3").on('click', function () {
        newLocation(15,-75,4);
    });

});
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you should change:

```
map.setCenter({
    lat : newLat,
    lng : newLng
});
```

to:

```
map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(newLat, newLng));
```